# i want to kill my sprite. how to kill it?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, kill

```
    import pygame as pygame , sys,time
    
    pygame.init()
    size = (700,500)
    window_game = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    
    _run_ = True
    
        
    
    white = (255,255,255) 
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
      
    
    
    class mySprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__ (self,cord_x,cord_y,picture,colorkey):
            super().__init__()
            self.image = pygame.Surface([0,0])
            self.image = pygame.image.load(picture)
            self.image.set_colorkey(colorkey)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = [cord_x,cord_y] 
            self.kill()
            
    
    placeSP_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    Clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 500
    while _run_:
    
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.QUIT
                sys.exit()
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        placeSP = [mySprite(mouse_pos[0],mouse_pos[1],'sp_1.png',white)]
        pygame.display.flip()
        placeSP_group.draw(window_game)
        placeSP_group.add(placeSP[:])
        Clock.tick(FPS)
```

now i want that my sprite get's killed and get the new mouse position
and window_game.fill('black')
dosen't work is there any thing you can do to fix it pls tell me...
what i wan't is every time my mouse moves i wan't kill the last sprite and create the other one with the current sprite pos.

Comment: yes it did work but then i keeps the last frame which then leave the sprite and if i try to to self.kill then it dosen't appear any sprite

Comment: could you use dots to split your text into sentences?

Comment: I don't see `window_game.fill('black')` in your code - so it can't work.

Comment: I don't understand your code - you create new `mySprite` which in `__init__` at once runs `kill()` to remove it. Why do you do this? And it may not work because `kill()` works with sprites in `Group()` but you run it before you add `[mySprite(...)]` to `placeSP_group`. You would have to first create sprite, next add to group, and later kill it. But why to do it. If you want to move it then simply create Sprite at start and later only change its position.

Comment: if you want to kill last sprite in group then maybe you should use `placeSP_group.sprites()[-1].kill()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `kill()` in wrong moment.

`kill()` works when `Sprite` is inside `Group` but you first create `Sprite` which try to use `kill()` and later you add this sprite to `Group`.

You should first create `Sprite`, next add to `Group` and later run `kill()` for first `Sprite` in `Group`

```
placeSP_group.sprites()[0].kill()
```

but normal `Group` doesn't have to keep sprites in order and better use

```
placeSP_group = pygame.sprite.OrderedUpdates()
```

---

Full working code. It display 5 sprites which follow mouse.

```
import pygame
import sys

# --- constants ---  # PEP8: `UPPER_CASE_NAMES` for constants

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)   # PE8: space after `,`
SIZE = (700, 500)
FPS = 50  # there is no need to use `500` because Python can't run so fast,
           # and monitors runs with 60Hz (eventually 120Hz) which can display 60 FPS (120 FPS)

# --- classes ---  # PEP8: `CamelCaseNames` for classes

class MySprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    def __init__(self, x, y, picture, colorkey):
        super().__init__()
        
        # you need one of them
        
        # load image
        #self.image = pygame.image.load(picture)
        
        # OR

        # create surface        
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10, 10))
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
        
        # ----
        
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)

        self.image.set_colorkey(colorkey)

# --- main ---

pygame.init()
window_game = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)

#placeSP_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
placeSP_group = pygame.sprite.OrderedUpdates()  # Group which keep order

sprite1 = MySprite(0, 0, 'sp_1.png', WHITE)
sprite2 = MySprite(0, 0, 'sp_1.png', WHITE)
sprite3 = MySprite(0, 0, 'sp_1.png', WHITE)
sprite4 = MySprite(0, 0, 'sp_1.png', WHITE)
sprite5 = MySprite(0, 0, 'sp_1.png', WHITE)
placeSP_group.add([sprite1, sprite2, sprite3, sprite4, sprite5])

clock = pygame.time.Clock()   # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables

running = True

while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            #running = False
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
            
    # create new Sprite
    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    new_sprite = MySprite(x, y, 'sp_1.png', WHITE)
    
    # add new Sprite at the end of OrderedUpdates()
    placeSP_group.add([new_sprite])
    
    # remove Sprite at the beginning of OrderedUpdates()
    placeSP_group.sprites()[0].kill()  

    # ---

    pygame.display.flip()
    
    window_game.fill('black') 
    placeSP_group.draw(window_game)
    
    clock.tick(FPS)
```